# javascript: removes all nodes in a linked list with a value greater than num

Tags: javascript, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

How to delete all the nodes from the list that are greater than the specified value? For example:

- List : 10->3->17->5->2->14->7
- Value: 9
- Output: 3->5->2->7

This is what I have done so far:

```
class Node { 
    constructor(data = null){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
        this.head = null;
    }
    setNextNode(node) {
        if (node instanceof Node || node === null) {
          this.next = node;
        } else {
          throw new Error('Next node must be a member of the Node class.');
        }
    }
    getNextNode() {
        return this.next;
    }
    removeHead() { 
        const removedHead = this.head;
        if (!removedHead) {
            return;
        }
        this.head = removedHead.getNextNode();
        return removedHead.data;
    }
}

const removeNodes = (head, num) => {;
    if (head == null) return null;
    if (head.data > num) {
       removeHead(head); //discard the entire list
        return null;
    }

    var current = head;

    while (true) {
        if (current.next == null) return head; //end of list
        if (current.next.data > num) break;
        current = current.next;
    }

    removeHead(current.next); //discard the rest of the list
    current.next = null; 
    return head;
}
```

Comment: `const arrayLTE9 = yourArray.filter(v=>v<=9);` will give you an Array with values less than or equal to 9. I would do that unless you want the original Array to be affected.

Comment: Does your current code not work?

Comment: @iota no it doesn't

Comment: @StackSlave I'll give that a shot thank you

Comment: why does it not work - what happens? 
can you perhaps provide some output - i.e. put some console.log statements in to show program flow